# Manipulate database of WordPress site with my own scripts

Tags: wordpress

I love WordPress as it provides plenty of great themes, good SEO and overall content management.

But I'm not always happy with WordPress's original "Add post" and "Edit post" features as it required manual work to provide the content for the site.

However all the data of WordPress site stored in the database which can be easily manipulated by 'handwritten' script (PHP for example). It'd look promising but I'd be afraid of crashing WordPress-specific data structure and invoke mistakes in the site work or even make it inaccessible. Moreover WordPress has its own caching and probably many other things I should take care about before I get started.

So my questions are:

1) Is it even possible and (more important) reasonable to manipulate the WordPress database by handwritten script?

2) If the answer for the 1st question is 'Yes' - is there any tools (for PHP in the first place) which can make this process more save and pleasant?

3) Is there any reading for the task I'd like to accomplish? I tried to Google a little bit but I didn't find any even close to this (I tried a queries like 'wordpress database manipulation', 'wordpress post by php script' and so on).

Comment: Typically you don't need to do an 'manual scripts'.. just work within what Wordpress offers as far as data manipulation. It provides all the tools you need... You mention having to manually provide content for the site but you can just use the REST api thats built in for example. This question is likely to get downvoted as its not a 'good' question to ask, it's not specific to code. Check out the wordpress developer documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to do this, it's safest to use the wordpress API and have your script do things through the API instead. That way if any database structures or features change, the API will incorporate those changes and you won't need to edit your code as much.

Read up on how to use the Wordpress API to make and edit posts. Here's an example: https://netmidas.com/blog/wordpress-rest-api-crud-example-with-a-post/